# Выборка DISTINCT и параметры ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Если я делаю следующий запрос

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_event 
FROM mes 
LEFT JOIN searchjur ON mes.id_event = searchjur.id 
WHERE to=58 
ORDER BY t5ime_mes DESC LIMIT 20
```

то у меня выборка происходит следующим образом. Сначала он выбирает все уникальные значения `id_event`, а потом уже сортирует результат этой выборки по полю `t5ime_mes`,
а как сделать, что бы выборка происходила по убыванию поля `t5ime_mes` , но при этом брало уникальные значения поля `id_event`?
Пробовал делать

```
SELECT `id`, `id_event`, max(`t5ime_mes`) 
FROM ( SELECT * 
       FROM `mes`
       ORDER BY `t5ime_mes` DESC ) as `new_table` 
GROUP BY `id_event`
```

но это тоже не дало положительного результата

Comment: попробуйте использовать group by

Comment: Тот же результат

Comment: надо немного перефразировать ваш вопрос: "как получить максимальные значения t5ime_mes для каждого id_event" и тогда это легко будет перевести на sql :) `select id_event, max(t5ime_mes) from .... group by id_event`

Comment: Я рано обрадовался ( Он сортирует по возрастанию id_event, а мне нужно t5ime_mes

Comment: Запрос SELECT `id_event`, max(`time_mes`) FROM `mes` LEFT JOIN `searchjur` ON `mes`.`id_event` = `searchjur`.`id` WHERE `to`=58  GROUP BY `id_event` DESC ORDER BY `t5ime_mes`

Comment: *что бы выборка происходила по убыванию поля t5ime_mes , но при этом брало уникальные значения поля id_event?* Мне не кажется это верным. Одному `id_event` соответствует несколько разных `t5ime_mes`. Вы хотите оставить для `id_event` только одну запись из всех... а с каким именно `t5ime_mes` из всех возможных? и почему? Ну или хотя бы покажите то, что хотите получить на показанных на скриншоте данных - опять же с объяснением, почему именно так.

Comment: В данном случае должны показать значения поля 6, 5, 4.

Comment: Но фильтр происходит по полю id_event. То есть запрос ищет все последние значения уникального поля столбца id_event и должен отобразить их от последних к началу.

Answer (score 0):

Есть варварский способ получить то, что ты хочешь увидеть (почти как в комментарии).
select Id_event, mes_to, MAX(t5ime_to) from table1 group by id_event order by MAX(t5ime_to) desc;
Но я не уверен в том, что это решит твою проблему.
[image: Пример с MIN, таблица exp1]

В комментарии добавить не могу. (

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id_event 
FROM mes 
LEFT JOIN searchjur ON mes.id_event = searchjur.id 
WHERE to=58 
GROUP BY id_event
ORDER BY MAX(t5ime_mes) DESC LIMIT 20
```